# Three python regular expressions around underscores

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'm helping someone with some file renaming at work using an application that supports python regular expression syntax. I tried a few expressions found on forums like `^[^_]+(?=_)` for a) below but it didn't work properly, and some others that didn't work. so, I figured I should reach out to someone who actually knows what they're doing. thanks for your help.

a) in the first expression I have to find all characters before the first underscore in patterns like this:

```
cannon_mac_23567_prsln_333
jones_james_343342_prsln_333
smith_john_223462_prsln_333
```

so, I have to get cannon, jones, and smith

b) in a separate expression I have to find all characters between the first and second underscore. so, I need to find mac, james, and john in the examples above.

c) in the last expression I have to find the first underscore

the way the renaming app works I have to do these regular expressions in three parts, like the above. thanks.

Comment: You should show what you've tried for each part.  How didn't your attempts work?

Comment: Updated my answer, should do what you want now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
1.  ^([^_]+)_
2.  _([^_]+)_ 
3.  ^[^_]_
```

Using re.match, as it matches at the beginning of the string.

*[Edit: As Cthulhu pointed out, you might be better of not using regular expressions for this, as it's faster and easier to use string methods]*

Comment: that is perfect. thank you! i made one mistake in my request. for step 2, can you include the trailing underscore? for example, it would find "james_" rather than "james"

Comment: For that you'd need to put the underscore _inside_ the parentheses instead of outside.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do it without regular expressions entirely, as you **know** your delimiter is the underscore.

Use the **[`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)**, and `index` methods.

```
'smith_john_223462_prsln_333'.split('_')[0] //(to extract smith)
'smith_john_223462_prsln_333'.split('_')[1] //(to extract john)
'smith_john_223462_prsln_333'.index('_') //(to get position of first underscore)
```

Comment: thanks but has to be regex. i'm using a desktop application for file renaming that supports python regular expression syntax. not actually using python

Answer (score 1):

Right, I misunderstood your question at first. While the `str.split` would definitely be a more elegant way to solve this, here are three regular expressions to suit your needs. I have no idea whether or not this application of yours will work with them. So take this with a grain of salt.

Please take a look at the [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library and the [MatchObject.span()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span) for further information.

As a single regex:

```
import re
line = "cannon_mac_23567_prsln_333"
In [1812]: match = re.match(r"(.+?)(\_)(.+?)\_", line)

In [1813]: match.groups()
Out[1813]: ('cannon', '_', 'mac')

In [1814]: match.span(2)[0] <-- second group, start. The first occurence of _
Out[1814]: 6

In [1815]: line[6]
Out[1815]: '_'
```

Seprated in a, b, c:

a:

```
import re
line = "cannon_mac_23567_prsln_333"
In [1707]: match = re.match(r"(.+?)\_", line)

In [1708]: match.groups()
Out[1708]: ('cannon',)
```

b:

```
In [1712]: match = re.match(r".+\_(.+?)\_", line)

In [1713]: match.groups()
Out[1713]: ('prsln',)
```

c:  Last one uses re.search for simplicity. `MatchObject.span()` returns a tuple of position `(start, end)`

```
In [1763]: match = re.search("\_", line)

In [1764]: match.span()[0]
Out[1764]: 6

In [1765]: line[6]
Out[1765]: '_'
```