# Pattern matching of filename between underscores and compare included date string to current datetime

Tags: python, regex, date, filenames, python-re

Similarly to the Topic to [Open only files containing dates of past seven days in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062958/open-only-files-containing-dates-of-past-seven-days-in-filename) I want to open only those files which follow a very rigid rule with respect to their naming and extract part of the filename to do a date comparison.

My filename is build like this

```
{Custom-prefix}_{SupplierName}_{8 digtit_date}.csv
an example:

myprefix_Shop_no24_20221009.csv
```

so the supplier name can have underscores in them. But each part of the string is divided by underscores as well.

I do have the complete list of for `{SupplierName}` but this can change over time and I would like to avoid a solution that hard codes them. The `{SupplierName}` can have numbers in them and they are of various length and include "_".

I tried this:

```
prefix = "Custom-prefix"
pattern = re.compile(fr"(?<={prefix})([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)([0-9]{8})(?=\.csv)")
# I get the filenames via os.walk
matched = pattern.search(filname)
```

but this seems to match everything that sits between "CustomPrefix" and ".csv".

```
pattern = re.compile(fr"(?<={prefix})([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(?=\.csv)")
```

Is giving me the exact same result. The way I understand this, I have to make regex aware, that it has to match the individual parts of the string and respect the underscore. so that each group of my filename:

```
 myprefix
_
Shop_no24
_
20221009
.csv
```

gets recognized. I found a solution to match to underscores in names [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257499/three-python-regular-expressions-around-underscores) but I am unfortunately not able to get the regex myself and match the found groups afterwards to do the date comparison.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Capture the date parts: `re.compile(fr"{prefix}(\w*)_(\d{{4}})(\d{{2}})(\d{{2}})\.csv")`. Note the double escaped literal braces in the f-string literal.

Comment: You may use: [`^Custom-prefix_(\w+)_(\d{8})\.csv$`](https://regex101.com/r/lLF5DO/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
pattern = re.compile(fr"{prefix}_(\w*)_(\d{{4}})(\d{{2}})(\d{{2}})\.csv")
```

Note the double escaped literal braces in the f-string literal.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Z9QB7g):

```py
import re
filename = "Custom-prefix_Shop_no24_20221009.csv"
prefix = "Custom-prefix"
pattern = re.compile(fr"{prefix}_(\w*)_(\d{{4}})(\d{{2}})(\d{{2}})\.csv")
matched = pattern.search(filename)
if matched:
    supplier, year, month, day  = matched.groups()
    print(f'supplier={supplier}, year={year}, month={month}, day={day}')
```

Output:

```
supplier=Shop_no24, year=2022, month=10, day=09
```

With `(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})` part, you capture all date parts into separate groups so that you can manipulate them however you see fit.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. The "if matched:" part is needed to  check that you got a result before you apply the group method on it i guess? Otherwise search would return None, which has no group method?

Comment: @NorrinRadd Yes, that is the best practice.